# Giving green a value somehow clears red

Tags: directx, hlsl, pixel-shader

I have a pixel shader in which I have the following part

```
imgcolor.b = 0;
imgcolor.r = 1 - dist1 / 5;
imgcolor.g = 0;
```

if I make the following change

```
imgcolor.b = 0;
imgcolor.r = 1 - dist1 / 5;
imgcolor.g = 1 - min(1,max(0,dist2));
```

where both dist1 and dist2 are float the red value becomes 0 in parts where it shouldn't be.
Why does this happen? How do I prevent it?

First case: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bq2irg4nsjarne2/good.jpg?dl=0

Second case: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jy0z2zk56h9jl96/wrong.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Link to shader's source(with comments): http://pastebin.com/3128bpkC

Comment: Can you post lossless screenshots? The jpeg compression artifacts make it difficult to see what's really going on.

Comment: If you right-click on the picture and choose view original you'll see the lossless version.

Comment: Stab in the dark here: Try initializing dist2

Comment: If only it were that easy :). No, initializing it doesn't make a difference.